# Cleaning up the whole trace of one's activity on ubuntu

Tags: unity-dash, history, cleanup

I am working on an ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
The computer I am working on is temporarily in my possession, given to me by my employer. So at some point I have to give it back.
What exactly should I consider while cleaning up my activities before giving the computer back. I know about Dash history and cleaning that.
But is there anything else in particular that I need to consider to take care of? I don't wanna leave any trace of my activities behind.
Thanks

Comment: Sudo apt-get install bleachbit -y

Comment: @hellomoto .. and how should that command help ?

Comment: Would it be an option to do a fresh install of 16.04 before returning the computer?

Comment: Bleachbit runs an easy graphical version to clean up unused files and folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete all files in your user's home folder. Don't forget the hidden ones.
- Use

  ```
  find / -user you_user_name
  ```

  to see if there are any other files belonging to your user and possibly remove them.
- If you can use `sudo`: Check the log files in `/var/log/` and maybe delete them.

Comment: This only finds files, who wants to do that manually, add in: find / type -user   -exec rm -rfi "{}" \;

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to clean all of the user activity traces is to delete its current account completely and recreate it. But first it's worth to wipe securely your sensitive data to avoid its recovery in the future.

**DATA WIPING**

If your home directory resides in a HDD, clean sensitive files with `wipe` utility. Install it:

```
sudo apt install wipe
```

Wipe files, for example, run for the file verysecurefile.odt:

```
wipe verysecurefile.odt
```

Issue

```
wipe -h
```

for additional information on wipe using.
If your home directory is on SSD - `wipe` is useless. The only SSD encryption can protect it from deleted data recovery.

**USER ACCOUNT RECREATING**

Assume your current user name is `bob` and you want to remove safely all of its data, to be sure all of its activity traces is wiped.

Create second user `alice`:

```
sudo adduser alice
```

Change `alice's` shell to `/bin/bash`

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash alice
```

Add `alice` to `sudo` group

```
sudo adduser alice sudo
```

Log out from `bob's` account and log in as `alice` using Ubuntu GUI. Open terminal being in `alice's`account session and run:

```
sudo userdel -r bob
```

to wipe all of the `bob's` activity traces - the account itself, home directory etc. Create `bob's` account again:

```
sudo adduser bob
```

Change `bob's` shell to `/bin/bash`

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash bob
```

Add `bob` to `sudo` group

```
sudo adduser bob sudo
```

Log out from `alice's` account and log in as `bob`. From recreated `bob's` account session open terminal and delete `alice's` account completely:

```
sudo userdel -r alice
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, this is what I was looking for, multiple options.